# Is it possible to lock a file programmatically? (IBM Connections 5.0)

Tags: ibm-connections

I am working with the IBM Connection APIs and I didn't find anything about the question of locking a file programmatically in the [documentation](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=File_content_ic50&content=apicontent). There is no way to do it?

I have seen that when a file is locked the metadata is changed:

- When it is not locked we have

`<td:lock type="HARD">`

- When it is locked (manually) we have something like that:

  `<td:lock type="HARD">
     <td:owner>
       <name>Jane Doe</name>
       <snx:userid>20[...]6E</snx:userid>
       <email>heloise.chauvel@chanel-corp.com</email>
       <snx:userState>active</snx:userState>
       </td:owner>
       <td:lockTime>2017-05-17T13:05:03.990Z</td:lockTime>
   </td:lock>`

So I could programmatically modify this metadata but is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to lock a file programmatically. There is no option in the API documentation and it is unauthorized to submit new metadata like I was explaining in my question.

So what I decided to do was to add a tag "locked" programmatically. No other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this specific method in the documentation but I believe it is possible if you post to:

```
/files/{auth}/api/document/{document-id}/lock?type=hard
```

with a content-type of 'text/plain' and a 'X-Update-Nonce' header, with an empty message body.

It is also possible to set it as part a [file update](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Updating_a_file_ic50&content=apicontent)